# Is a quasiconvex function always the monotone image of a convex function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, monotone-functions

Not every [quasiconvex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function) is convex. 
However, given a quasiconvex function $f:X\to \Bbb{R}$ (where $X$ is a convex subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$), can we always find a *monotone* or at least non-decreasing $m:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ and a *convex* function $\tilde f:X\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $m\circ \tilde f= f$ ?

Comment: I don't think so. Consider $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$. What would $m$ and $\tilde{f}$ be in this case?

Comment: Ha ha! Nevermind, $f$ is itself non-decreasing. So $m=f$ and $\tilde$ f as the identity would work.

Comment: Another shot: $f(x) = \lfloor |x| \rfloor$...

Comment: @MichaelGrant Then $\tilde f(x)=|x|$ and $m(t)=\lfloor t \rfloor$ works again.